# Issue creating AWS security group through API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

```
AWS PHP SDK Version 3.188.1 - 2021-08-09
```

I have the following PHP code:

```
require ..'/aws_sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$Ec2Client = Ec2Client('mykey', 'mysecretkey', '2016-11-15', 'us-east-1');

$params = [
    'DryRun' => true,
    'GroupName' => 'mygroupSG',
    'Description' => 'My Security Group'
];

results = SecurityGroup($Ec2Client, $params);

function Ec2Client($access_Key, $SecretAccessKey, $version, $region)
{
    try {
        $ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
            'key' => $access_Key, 
            'secret' => $SecretAccessKey,
            'version' => $version,
            'region' => $region
        ]); 
    } catch (Ec2Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    return $ec2Client;
}

function SecurityGroup($Ec2Client, $params)
{
    try {
        return $Ec2Client->createSecurityGroup($params);
    } catch (Ec2Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex);
        die ($ex->getAwsErrorCode());
    }    
}
```

When I run this piece of code, I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Ec2\Exception\Ec2Exception' with message 'Error executing "CreateSecurityGroup" on "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>MalformedQueryString</title> </head> </htm (truncated...) Unable to parse error information from response - Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as XML' GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>MalformedQueryString</title> </head> </htm (truncated...) in /aws_sdk/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /aws_sdk/GuzzleHttp/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException in /aws_sdk/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 195
```

I verified separately that the Ec2Client was properly created. I am following the sample from the AWS docs, but that's a bit confusing as there are multiple examples, that using different arguments lists. Any ideas?

## SOLUTION:

The problem was in a the credentials file, in my .aws directory. It had bad credentials, so I was not authenticated properly. but I was not getting an error message when the Ec2Client was created.

Comment: Can you verify that you can create the SG using AWS CLI executed under same `$access_Key, $SecretAccessKey` and region?

Comment: The problem was in a the credentials file, in my .aws directory. It had bad credentials, so I was not authenticated properly. but I was not getting an error message when the Ec2Client was created.

Comment: Glad it works now. You can answer your own question if you want and accept it as well.